# Build a reactive API server messages from Kafka in server sent event manner with Spring webflux

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-webflux, kafka-consumer-api, reactive

I'm working on building a reactive web service that's connected to a Kafka topic, and it will support a reactive API that all requestor calling this API will receive new messages from Kafka as server sent events. (Originally thinking about the API will support keywords and will only receive kafka messages containing this keywords but figured out that Kafka doesn't support that). I'm pretty new to reactive and spring webflux, my current plan is to subscribe to Kafka, send the message from Kafka to a sink, then the controller returns sink.asFlux. But obviously, my understanding of the sink was not correct. Any suggestion would be very helpful :)

**Controller**

```
@RestController
 @RequestMapping(path = "/sse") 
public class SSEController {      
    @Autowired     private Flux<String> flux;   
   
    @CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "*")     
    @GetMapping(value = "/listen/{keyword}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)     
    public Flux<String> listenToKeyword(@PathVariable String keyword) {
         // TODO: how to filter out by keyword as data stream 
        return flux; 
    }

      @CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "*") 
    @GetMapping(value = "/listenall", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
     public Flux<String> listenToAll() {
         return flux; 
    } }
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration 
public class KafkaConfiguration { 
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());  

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}") 
    private String bootStrapServers;  

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}") 
    private String kafkaTopic;     

     @Bean 
    public Sinks.Many<String> sink() {
         return Sinks.many().replay().latest();
     }   
       
    @Bean
     public Flux<String> flux(Sinks.Many<String> sink) { 
        return sink.asFlux(); 
    }  

    @Bean(name = "kafkaReceiver")
     public KafkaReceiver kafkaReceiver() {  
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();         
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServers);         
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName()); 
        props.put(
                 ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
         props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"); 
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);  
        try { 
            ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<String, String>create(props).commitInterval(Duration.ZERO).commitBatchSize(0).subscription(Collections.singleton(kafkaTopic)); 
            KafkaReceiver<String, String> kafkaReceiver = KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions).receive().publishOn(Schedulers.newSingle("sample", true)).concatMap(m -> this.sink()::emitNext); // TODO: how to emit to the sink
             return kafkaReceiver; 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            logger.debug("", e); 
            throw e;
         } 
    }
 }
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, to achieve this behaviour you need an in memory queue, take a look at this: https://github.com/oktadev/okta-spring-webflux-react-example/blob/react-app/reactive-web/src/main/java/com/example/demo/ProfileCreatedEventPublisher.java

Comment: Hi @Nico, from the SSE example in this demo you shared, I'm wondering will the client receive all profiles created ever since, or just the ones created after the server received the call? Thanks! This demo is super helpful to me

Comment: This depends, so If you are populating all of the profiles into the queue and you are not removing them from it (after consuming) you will be able to do that, but you have to remove them somehow to not fill the whole queue.